# Abstract error when splitting a string

Tags: string, delphi, split, delimiter

when using this procedure, i am getting an abstract error (that's all it says). i use this procedure in other projects, this is the first time i've run into it. i'm not sure if it has to do with the syntax of the input string.

```
procedure SplitString(const Delimiter: Char; Input: string; const Strings: TStrings);
begin
  //Delimits or splits the received string, returns TStrings array
   Assert(Assigned(Strings)) ;
   Strings.Clear;
   Strings.Delimiter := Delimiter;
   Strings.StrictDelimiter := True; //needed otherwise whitespace is used to delimit
   Strings.DelimitedText := Input;
end;
```

the application calls like this:

```
      try
        LBOMPartLine := TStrings.Create;
        SplitString(',','C:\DATA\Parts\PART4.PS.0,10,10',LBOMPartLine);
      ...
```

I've removed some of the debug code that highlighted the fact that the procedure fails, nothing after or before. Can I not use a comma as a separator?

Comment: Could you show the literal error message? Is it just a pop-up dialog that just says "abstract error"? Is it the same version of Delphi as in the other projects? What version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
LBOMPartLine := TStrings.Create;
```

`TStrings` is an abstract class, and you can't create an instance of it. You have to create an instance of a descendant, such as `TStringList` instead. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TStrings) clearly says (**emphasis** added):

> Derive a class from TStrings to store and manipulate a list of strings. **TStrings contains abstract or, in C++ terminology, pure virtual methods and should not be directly instantiated.**

You typically use `TStrings` as the type of a parameter that a function or procedure receives, so that you can accept any `TStrings` descendant such as a `TStringList`, `TComboBox.Items', or`TMemo.Lines`.

The solution is to create an instance of a descendant:

```
var
  LBOMPartLine: TStrings; // or more clearly, TStringList
begin
  LBOMPartLine := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SplitString(',','C:\DATA\Parts\PART4.PS.0,10,10',LBOMPartLine);
    // Do whatever else
  finally
    LBOMPartLine.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

`TStrings` is an abstract class, and thats why you're getting abstract error. `LBOMPartLine` has to be declared as `TStringList` instead, which is descendant of `TStrings` class.

Compiler warns you about instantiating a class that has abstract methods - I suggest that you don't ignore warnings and try to write proper code, without them.

Also, class creation should be done **outside** of `try/finally` block:

```
some_class := TSomeClass.Create;
try
  ..
finally
  some_class.Free;
end;
```